# Ventana taakeng.exe se abre por un programa de consola

Tags: c#, cmd

Tengo varios programas de consola hechos en C#, pero algunos de ellos me están levantando una ventana de cmd titulada `taskeng.exe` cada vez que se ejecutan desde el programador de tareas. La cuestión es que no todos levantan esta ventana.

También tengo el problema que cuando se lanzan desde el programador de tareas, no terminan, en cambio cuando los lanzo desde su carpeta origen estos si terminan en tiempo justo (dependiendo la tarea) e identifican la ventana del cmd con el nombre del `exe` correcto. Alguna idea??

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Para poder ayudarte necesitaríamos mas datos. Por ejemplo, que hacen esos programas. Sería tambien muy interesante si pudieras preparar un [mcve] que puedieramos probar

Comment: puede que las task de windows sean ejecutadas en un entorno que define esa aplicacion para levantar la consola, pero me llama la atencion que mencionas solo algunas, porque si fuera asi lo haria en todos los casos

Comment: relacionado a no terminar la ejecucion habria que ver que tipo de aplicaciones se trata, son de consola o ventana? la consola suele terminar siemre pero la ventana puede que ante un error se quede esperando

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones! Respecto de lo que hacen estos programas es: llamar a procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server que ejecutan consultas, estos devuelven los dataset y son utilizados para llenar un Excel que se envía por correo. Hace poco me di cuenta de este problema, ya que ciertas alarmas no me estaban llegando en tiempo, y algunas simplemente no llegaban. El servidor tuvo un deterioro en su rendimiento, y lo están evaluando. Ahorita me encuentro comparando líneas de código, referencias y más con programas que no lanzan esta ventana, con los que si.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la causa del porque se abre esta ventana de cmd, les explixo: cuando programas una tarea en el programador de tareas de Windows, en la primera pestaña te ofrece varios parámetros de ejecución, el nombre, descripción y la opción de ejecutar la tarea solamente si el usuario se encuentra logueado (que es la causa de que se abra esta ventana) o ejecutar si el usuario está dentro o no, al seleccionar esta última opción dejo de aparecer. Espero les sirva a alguno.